# Rearrange javascript object - keys using .sort() are not kept as on the array which is being sorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

```
var tagged={"tagged":[
{"positionX":11,"positionY":13},
{"positionX":12,"positionY":18},
{"positionX":10,"positionY":20}
]};
```

So I have this object,

I need to reconstruct it so that it ends up looking as follows:

```
var tagged={"tagged":[
{"positionX":10,"positionY":20},
{"positionX":11,"positionY":13},
{"positionX":12,"positionY":18}
]};
```

Sorted by positionX ASC.

I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var tagged={"tagged":[
        {"positionX":11,"positionY":13},
        {"positionX":12,"positionY":18},
        {"positionX":10,"positionY":20}
        ]};

        tagged=tagged.tagged;

        var newtagged=new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < tagged.length; i++) {
        newtagged[i]=tagged[i].positionX;   
        }

        var sorted=newtagged.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});

        $(sorted).each(function(k,v){   
        alert(v);
        });
</script>
```

There indeed is a successful sort but the keys are incorrect in the new "sorted" array.

So  I am unable to retrieve all the correct values in the original object based on the original reading of the keys, I mean, without the original key of sorted I don't know to what belongs the sorted "positionX", that way I am unable to retrieve its corresponding positionY in array tagged. .sort(function(){}); assigns new keys to sorted array.

Comment: `sorted=tagged.tagged.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a.positionX-b.positionX});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you wish to sort tagged according to the value of positionX. If that's the case you can simply pass a function to sort that compares the attributes.

```
var sorted=tagged.sort(function(a,b){return a.positionX-b.positionX});
```

Comment: The sorting is actually on the tagged.tagged array.

Comment: @Christophe so I originally thought (it's in an earlier version of my answer if you see the history :) ) but then I noticed `tagged=tagged.tagged`

Comment: I think tagged=tagged.tagged is just part of the failed attempt.